# Radix/LSD sort queue c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, radix-sort

I wrote  **radix sort** using queue by myself, because we use it  theoretically during class and it appeared very interesting to me . I got familiar with algorith and read  [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751815/radix-sorting-with-using-queue) about radix sort and followed by instructions [ylc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217976/ylc)

I tested it by using pseudo random numbers and it looks like it is doing its job - array is sorted at the end . I have some doubts as to the proper memory management. Exacly to the removing form queue and inserting it into the array.

There is first question: **Are there any leaks of memory ?**

---

I also tought about complexity of this algorithm. I read [this artticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Efficiency) about efficiency.

> ***n*** - size of array
>   ***w*** - number of positions in our max number
>   ***c1*** = comparison in max function - done **n** times
>   ***c2*** = insertion at queue - done **n*w** times
>   ***c3*** = remove from queue - done **n*w** times
>   ***c4*** = insertion at array - done **n*w** times
>
> **T(n) = n*c1 + n*w*(c2+c3+c4) = O(w*n)**

Memory complexity will be **T(n) = n * sizeof(node)**

Secound question: **Is this reasoning logically?**

---

## Radix-sort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct list
{
    int key;
    list *next;
};
//pointers to structure to do queue
list* ptr [10], *head[10];

//function that returns the maximum of the table
int maxi (int *t, int n)
{
    int max= t[0];
    for(int i = 1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (t[i]>max)
        max = t[i];
    }
    return max;
}
//sort
void radx(int *t,int  n )
{
    list * tmp, *temp;  //the queue management
    int exp = 10;                       
    int k, j = 0 , l=1;
    int max = maxi(t,n);        


    for(int i=0; i=max*10/exp; i++)
    {   
    //insertion to queue
        for(int i =0 ; i<n; i++)
        {
            k = ((t[i]%exp)/l); //digit of our position 
            if(head[k] == NULL)
            {
                head[k] = new list;
                head[k]->key = t[i];
                head[k]->next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = head[k];
                tmp->next;
                while (tmp->next)
                {
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
                ptr[k] = new list;
                ptr[k] -> key = t[i];
                tmp->next = ptr[k];
                ptr[k]->next = NULL;
            }
        }
        //remove and writeback at table
        for(int i= 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            tmp = head[i];
            while(tmp)
            {   
                t[j] = tmp->key;
                temp = tmp;
                tmp = tmp->next;
                delete temp;
                j++;
            }
            head[i] = NULL;
        }

            exp *= 10;  //next position of number
            l   *= 10;
            j    = 0;
    }


}
void Random (int n, int a, int b, int *t)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        t[i] =  rand()% (b-a+1)+a;  
    }
}
int main()
{   
    srand(time(0));
    int n, a, b;
    cout<<"How many elements: ";
    cin>>n;
    int *t = new int [n];
    cout<<endl<<"Range from to: ";
    cin>>a>>b;

    Random(n, a, b, t);

    radx(t, n);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    cout<<t[i]<<" ";


    delete []t;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: To check for memory leaks use a tool like valgrind. To check your logic, step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: Looks like you should rather ask your question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where you can have your code reviewed. If you explicitly tell that you don't want memory leaks, people might look at that specifically.

Comment: Also there are probably memory leaks: you're not using standard collections or smart pointers. If an exception is thrown from your algorithm at some point (like `std::bad_alloc`), your allocated memory will never be deleted and your algorithm will simply leak.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that this even compiles without warnings. Your inner for-loops re-declare the variable i, which hides the outer for-loop variable i. This is typically bound to get you into trouble. Also, look carefully at: "for(int i=0; i=max*10/exp; i++)". This is re-assigning the value of i when doing the condition check. I seriously doubt that this is what you want.